# Performance of SQL vs. stored procedures in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, relational-database

One of my friend told that they use stored procedure for any small or big SQL statement in their organisation. That's why I want to clear my doubt. I have two different doubt please try 
to help me out. I will be obliged.

1. which will run faster, normal SQL or procedure of that normal SQL?
2. And which is best for the programability in case of normal SQL statement?

Both of the above question is only for SQL and PLSQL of Oracle related?

Comment: It is quite unclear what do you mean by your second question. Explain more detailed please. As of your first question: stored procedures is just a method of code organization like in any other programming language. It makes code divided to logical units for better readability, easier maintanence and future re-use. There is no significant difference in between SQL statement issued stand-alone and as a part of stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to put something like `select count(*) from table` into a stored procedure. The overhead of calling the stored procedure is certainly higher than executing the statement directly.

If you have some code that selects and updates many rows, putting that into a stored procedure will probably faster than executing the same code from some client, because you save the network traffic/delay involved.

However, performance is not the only reason to do that. Some organizations will not grant any access to any table to the client, but provide a set of stored procedures to access data. That way, you can do additional security checks in your stored procedures. If your database client is not a web server, but some frontend running on a client PC, someone could debug the client to find out the password, then connect to the database using a tool like sqlplus. If the only way to access the actual data is through stored procedures, and these stored procedures won't allow more than 10 rows returned, it's much harder for a client to `select * from anytable` to get a dump of all the data. Additionally, of your stored procedures are the only way to write to the database, they can do a lot of sanity checking before modifying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will perform better with PLSQL Function and Procedures, Using PLSQL units, Queries gets parsed once by the Oracle Database, then everytime that function/procedure is called the execution plans chosen by the Oracle optimizer gets reused.

select vendor_name from all_vendors where vendor_id = 123;
-- Oracle will do a Hard Parse everytime

select get_vendor_name(123) from dual;
-- Oracle will reuse the execution plans, Soft Parse.

Many Organizations will develop in multiple platforms and clients so PLSQL API will improve data consistency and also hide the business logic.

Comment: It is not true that a SQL statement will be hard-parsed every time.  And even if the value 123 changes, a bind variable can be used to eliminate hard-parsing.